# Can Jiddu Krishnamurthy's teachings be considered Buddhist in nature?

Tags: philosophy

There was a guy named [Jiddu Krishnamurthy](http://jiddu-krishnamurti.net/). He talked a lot about conditioning, awareness and to see the things as they are. One of the content from the hyperlink is

> His aim was to set humanity free. **He maintained that the individual is freed by becoming aware of their own psychological conditioning,** and that this awakening will enable them to give love to another.

My question is

- Was his teachings Buddhists in nature?
- Do any Buddhist teachers or philosophers opine about him? If yes, in what ways?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be contrary to [this policy](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1784/254).

Comment: @ChrisW I didnt share.  I found after asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Was his teachings Buddhists in nature?**

This is a quote from the page you referenced ...

> Krishnamurti said: "I maintain that Truth is a pathless land, and you cannot approach it by any path whatsoever, by any religion, by any sect."

... so, according to him, accoding to that, maybe not (not in name).

From the same page ...

> Krishnamurti was raised within the Theosophical Society to become an incarnation of Maitreya, the messianic Buddha.

... so he was presumably (I don't know) exposed to some kind[s] of Buddhist doctrine.

**Do any Buddhist teachers or philosophers opine about him? If yes, in what ways?**

Well I don't know about him in particular.

[This answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3810/254) says that the Theosophists (I think these were an early 20th-century European group) were trying to consolidate all religions into one -- to say that all religions were essentially the same or One in some way.

I think I've seen some people (who would call themselves themselves Buddhist) disagree with *that* doctrine, and disparage the Theosophists, so ...

See also e.g. [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/12650/254) -- someone leaving the "Theosophical" society to found a "Buddhist" society

Comment: Actually, just simple google search gives so much material on 'Buddha and Krishnamurthy'. It seems there is indeed a strong association between the two.

Comment: When K visited Bodhgaya with Annie Besant (then president of the Theosophical Society) K pointed out to her that he remembered the place as he had been at this place in his previous births as a monk-a part of the Buddha Sangha.

Comment: The book 'Lives of Alcyone' by CW Leadbeater (Theosophical Society) which supposedly chronicles the previous lives of J Krishnamurti mentions that K was a monk in the Sangha of the Buddha in 2 previous lives. K took robes and learnt Dhamma at the feet of Lord Buddha.